# Hacker Rank Java String Tokens

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on the [*Java String Tokens*](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-string-tokens/problem) on HackerRank. My code is as following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        // Write your code here.
        scan.close();
        // if length is 0
        if (s.length() == 0 || s == null) {
            System.out.println(0);
            return;
        }

        // It seems we need to remove some spaces
        s = s.trim();


        String[] words = s.split("[ |!|,|\\?|\\.|_|'|@|]+");
        System.out.println(words.length);

        for (String word: words){
            System.out.println(word);
        }

        
    }
}
```

It has passed most tests but failed when the input is null. I've attached a screenshot in this question:
[image]

So, can anyone plz explain what happened here? And how can I fix it?
Thank you so much!

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Split a string by non word characters? If so it's just (\W+)

Comment: 1) `nextLine()` cannot return `null`, so `s` cannot be `null`, making the `s == null` superfluous. --- 2) `s.length() == 0` is better written as `s.isEmpty()`. --- 3) You should move `s = s.trim()` up before the empty string check, so a line of nothing but spaces is handled correctly.

Comment: with `if (s.length() == 0 || s == null) {` check the null first

Comment: @ScaryWombat No need, see my earlier comment, but a generally valid observation.

Comment: For anyone wanting to see the full challenge description: [Java String Tokens | HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-string-tokens/problem)

Answer (score 1):

Regex `"[ |!|,|\\?|\\.|_|'|@|]+"` is extraneous.

- Do not separate characters in a `[ ]` [character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes) by the `|` [OR pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical), since that pattern only applies outside a character class.
- There is no need to escape `?` and `.` in a character class, since they are not special characters there.

Correct regex would be `[ !,?._'@]+` or `[^A-Za-z]+`.

---

The main problem with the code in the question is that `split()` may return an array where the first element is an empty string.

*Example 1:* Input `",X,"` will return `["", "X"]`. The empty string before the leading `,` is included, and the empty string after the trailing `,` is excluded, because **the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) says so**: *"Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array"*.

*Example 2:* Input `""` will return `[""]`, because **the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) explicitly says so**: *"If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string"*. Note how the "trailing empty string" rule is not applied to this specific use case.

*Example 3:* Input `",,"` will return `[]`, because trailing empty strings are excluded.

In examples 1 and 2, that leading empty string should be ignored.

I'll leave the actual fixing of the code to you, since this *is* your challenge to solve.

Comment: I modified the regex and moved "s = s.trim()" right after the "scan.close()" and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```java
if (scan.hasNext()) {
    s = scan.nextLine();
} else {
    System.out.println(0);
    return;
}
```

I edited your code a bit. For no `String` you have to use `Scanner.hasNext()`. If there is a `String` you will read it, otherwise just `return` and print `0`.

Comment: but there you just read the first string and not multiple lines, like the question

Comment: @auryn31 yeah right but on that question the input is only one string line

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with .trim(), move it before s.length()
my working code

```
import java.util.*;

 public class StringTokens {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    // Write your code here.
    s = s.trim();
    // if length is 0
    if (s.length()>400000){
        return ;
    }else if (s.length()==0 || s == null){
        System.out.println(0);
        return ;
    }else{ 

    // It seems we need to remove some spaces
    
    String[] words = s.split("[!,?.*_'@\\ ]+");

    int count = words.length;
    System.out.println(count);

    for (String word : words){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
    scan.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution success with all test case

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        if (s.length() > 1 && s.length() < 400000) {
            String textFiltered = s.trim();

            if (textFiltered.length() > 0) {
                String[] words = textFiltered.split("[!,?.*_'@\\ ]+");

                int count = words.length;
                System.out.println(count);

                for (String word : words) {
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(0);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need remove leading empty element in tokens array.

```
private static String[] getTokens(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
        return new String[0];
    }
    String[] tokens = s.trim().split("[^a-zA-Z]+"); // or [^A-Za-z]+
    if (tokens != null && tokens.length > 0 ) {
        if (tokens[0].isEmpty()) {
            return Arrays.copyOfRange(tokens, 1, tokens.length);
        } else {
            return tokens;
        }
    }
    return new String[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer of that question all test case will be passed

[image: You can see the screen shot of that test case which was passed]
you can see code bellow which is work properly

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scan.nextLine().trim();
        scan.close();
       
        // Check if the trimmed input string is empty
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(0);
        } else {
            // Split the string into tokens based on the specified pattern
            String[] tokens = str.split("[ !,?._'@]+");
            
            // Print the number of tokens
            System.out.println(tokens.length);
            
            // Print each token
            for(String token : tokens){
                System.out.println(token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```